Why is the wind modifier manipulating my object as if my object is parented to it?
for some reason i cant move the wind modifier around without it also moving my object with it.
ive see tutorials where this is not happening for them. granted they are old tutorials but it dosnt make sense that i cannot move and position it independently so that i can aim in desired direction without moving my effected object. this is happening in a bone stock scene
Im in Blender 4.3 and 4.2


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

hello it's not clear what you mean, if you move the Wind it will change the cloth direction, what's the problem exactly?

@moonboots im trying to position it so that the wind blows the shirt from the side very slightly. but the shirt is literally parented to it for some reason, this is happening before i play to get the simulation. ive seen tutorials where this isnt the case. the modifier can be moved around to position the direction of the wind

first thing, make sure that the shirt is not parented to the wind, if it's not the case, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
